# Adding two sprites by replacing another sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I want to add two sprites by replacing one sprite on touch. I tried the following code. it works fine only when sprite is horizontal. How to make it work if sprite is moving or not horizontal.

I am using cocos2d box2d physics.

```c
CCLOG(@"Touch Detected");
CGPoint pos=touchedSprite.position;

[touchedSprite removeSelf];

LHSprite *myNewSprite = [loader createSpriteWithName:@"Red_10" fromSheet:@"images" fromSHFile:@"BreakGlassResources" ];
myNewSprite.uniqueName=@"Red_10";
myNewSprite.tag=BRICK;
[myNewSprite transformPosition:ccp(pos.x,pos.y)];
myNewSprite.anchorPoint=ccp(1,0.5);
[myNewSprite registerTouchBeganObserver:self selector:@selector(touchBeginOnSprites:)];

LHSprite *myNewSprite1 = [loader createSpriteWithName:@"Blue_10" fromSheet:@"images" fromSHFile:@"BreakGlassResources" ];
myNewSprite1.uniqueName=@"Blue_10";
myNewSprite1.tag=BRICK;
[myNewSprite1 transformPosition:ccp(pos.x+myNewSprite.size.width,pos.y)];
myNewSprite1.anchorPoint=ccp(1,0.5);
```

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: what you have done in touchBeginOnSprites method ?

Comment: I'm handling touches in that method. If i touch a sprite with name "aaa" that should be replaced with two sprites.

Comment: as this code works in one case, it seems that your problem is not in this part of code. share your code of touch detection.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code snippet, you're never setting the new sprites positions. The `anchorPosition` and `transformPosition` are relative to the sprite itself and defines anchors for position and transform, but does not position the sprite itself. the `position` property is what you're looking for.

Comment: I have changed the rotation property of my newly added sprites to touchedSprite's rotation. This helped me. Thanks for your reply Stephane Delcroix.

Comment: I didn't change position, instead i set rotation property.